Pywhatkit doesn't send message on Raspberry Pi
I have been working on a Python script to automatically send whatsapp messages at a certain time using Pywhatkit. The code worked fine, but since I didn't want to keep my laptop open to run the script, I now run the script on a Raspberry Pi 4. Yet, when I run this script from my terminal on the Raspberry Pi (Raspberry IOS software is installed), it only opens web whatsapp and inserts the message, but it doesn't send the message and closes the tab. I have tried many things to solve this (eg use the press enter from the keyboard package, increase waiting time), but nothing seems to work. Although I use a more elaborate Python script, the very basis of it is already not working on the Raspberry, and therefore I include this Python code:
import pywhatkit 
import pyautogui
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('phone_number', 'message', 15, 20, 35, tab_close
= True)

Does anyone of you know what might be the cause of this? I was thinking that maybe it is due to accessibility options on the Raspberry or something? Hope that anyone knows and thanks in advance!

if you don't get error message when you run it in console/terminal then we have no idea what can make problem.

no I don't get an error message.... it only doesn't send the message and close the tab. I was thinking that I can maybe be due to some settings (on a Mac you have to give permissions to the terminal to control the things necessary to send the message in the 'Accessibility' menu), but I read that this is normally already given on a Raspberry Pi.

if it doesn't show any error message when you run script manually in console/terminal then we have not clue what can make problem. I have Raspberry 3 but without GUI (only text mode) so I don't know if I can even test it.

I tested it on notebook with Linux Mint and it doesn't click message to send it. I use Firefox but I can't test if the same problem is in Chrome or Edge - maybe problem makes browser.

it seems this module is 2 years old - see date on pypi.org. Maybe you have to install from GitHub PyWhatKit. You can also check issues on GitHub - it seems there is one problem with Raspberry Issues with running PyWhatKit on RPi (Ubuntu) but it has no answer.

I tested on Linux Mint and it has problem to send ENTER when I run code in interactive mode in IPython or BPython but it works correctly when I run it in script python script.py

Thank you for all the suggestions. I have tried running the code in script, tried different browsers and installing PyWhatkit via Github. This doesn't solve the problem yet (still doesn't press ENTER when running the script). I will try out some more possible solutions, and if I find it, post it here.

I was wondering whether installing another operating system on the Raspberry Pi might work. Currently, I have Raspberry Pi Os installed, but now I am looking into another operating system (as a read that it worked on Linux Mint). I was wondering whether anyone has tips or suggestions for this?

I have no idea if new OS will help. Maybe it is different problem. I have Raspberry but without installed GUI/Windows (only text mode) so I can't check if it would work on my computer.
